# How to set a turtle's colour to match another turtle?

Tags: netlogo

This one is pretty simple but I keep running into problems around how colours are stored. Both of the following produce an error saying colour should be three numbers for RGB.

let temp [color] of topTurtle
ask turtles [set color temp]

or

ask turtles [set color [color of topturtle]]

What's the correct way to do this please?

Comment: Are you by any chance working in a beta version of Netlogo? On the web version they are currently testing our RGB values for colors

Answer (score 1):

Your second option should be `ask turtles [set color [color] of topturtle]`, you put the brackets wrong.

Other than that error, both options work just fine for me.
If I enter the following lines in the command center, they work just fine.

```
crt 5 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
let temp [color] of turtle 0 ask turtles [set color temp]
```

The same goes for

```
crt 5 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
ask turtles [set color [color] of turtle 0]
```

Comment: Yep, there was an error earlier in my code. Thanks.